Meaning of "Host key"
Remoting in to a terminal server with Remmina, the right-hand Ctrl key is reserved for Remmina. Its function, depending on what one is reading, pertains either to Remmina's "Host Key" or to "Grab[bing] all keys."
It's a pain not to be able to use both Ctrl keys, but, before I change the key mapping in Remmina's preferences, what does "Host key" or "grab all keys" mean? What would I be disabling by remapping that key?

Some keystrokes, like ^C, ^D, ^Z, can have local effect, or can be "grabbed", and sent to the remote to take effect there. The "grab all keys" function sends ALL keystrokes to the remote. The "Host key" reverts to local interpretation. If you remap the key you will lose this capability, and possibly befuddle Remmina.
